# newly created CustomEvent has no own property("type") so jQuery fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work on a very basic class that uses (very) private events.

Since I don't want this class to be jQuery dependent, I use plain `CustomEvent`s (although I work with jQuery)

Surprise one was when jQuery failed with triggering my event, surprise 2 was that jQuery is testing `hasOwnProperty("type")`on the CustomEvent, and this is FALSE

In short: (Edit: `JunctionEvent` was missleading - its only a string "ju-ac" only - so I changed it in my example )

```
    junctionevent = "ju-ac"

    e = new CustomEvent(junctionevent, {bubbles: options.bubbles, composed: true})
    console.log e, e.type, e.hasOwnProperty("type")
```

says ("ju-ac" is the name or type of the event in this phase of development):

```
ju-ac { target: null, isTrusted: false, eventPhase: 0, bubbles: true, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: true, timeStamp: 9808, cancelBubble: false, … }
 ju-ac 
 false
```

So the Event has a "property" type, has the name "ju-ac" but not a Property named type?

What do I wrong? (or what is jQuery doing wrong?)

EDIT: I just learned, that jQuery can't handle plain CustomEvents as event input, it handles these like event data (as any other object on input) - this bet I has lost. 
This does not change my question,: why has the event after creation a property `type` with a string "xxxx" but hasOwnProperty("type") returning FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see the property `type` in your newly created CustomEvent instance, while at the same time you get `false` when using the `hasOwnProperty('type')` method invocation, is because the type property is an inherited property from the `Event` Object through the prototype chain and not a property directly owned by the newly created instance.

So, instance `e` inherits properties from its constructor, the `CustomEvent`, while `CustomEvent` inherits properties from its own constructor, the `Event` Object which is the owner of the `type` property.

You can follow the prototype chain all the way up to the `Event` Object and see how the `hasOwnProperty("type")` returns true like this:

```
let e = new CustomEvent("ju-ac");

e.type; // "ju-ac";
e.hasOwnProperty("type");   // false

// One step deep into the prototype chain
e.__proto__.constructor;   // CustomEvent
e.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("type");   // false

// Two steps deeper into the prototype chain
e.__proto__.__proto__.constructor;   // Event
e.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("type");   // true
```

Event: *"CustomEvent, I am your father!"*

CustomEvent: *"Noooooo!"*

Comment: I stepped into it - again :/ - thx. (and BTW jQuery does it wrong, too :) ) (has___own___propery - yes.)